# How to disable Google Map's Satellite view?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on Google Maps Javascript API V 3.

Everything is working fine but I want to disable the MAP button which appears in the top right area with SATELLITE button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

When you enable the map and passes the options to it, you have the chance to specify a mapTypeControlOptions. These have an Array that specifies what kind of maptype's you will allow the user to be able to see. It can be seen here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeControlOptions.

If you don't want the user to have any options as to the maptypes, you can also specify that by setting the maps mapTypeControl to false.

Comment: Setting mapTypeControl to false definitely vanishes the control but how can I customize it so that  mapTypeControl only contains SATELLITE and TERRAIN buttons?

Comment: That is what the mapTypeControlOptions should do.. It holds an array where you can specify that SATELLITE and TERRAIN are the options the user should see.

Comment: I don't know if it's a v3 thing, but if someone wishes to completly hide this control, setting `mapTypeControl` to `false` doesn't work. Instead what worked for me (in v3) was setting: `mapTypeControlOptions: { mapTypeIds: [] }`

Answer (score 145):

```js
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: **Your LatLng object**,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID]
    }, // here´s the array of controls
    disableDefaultUI: true, // a way to quickly hide all controls
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE 
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); // displays in <article id="map_canvas"></article>
//map.mapTypeControl = false; // OPTIONAL: hides the map control
```

Answer (score 65):

Disable Satellite option:

```
mapTypeControl: false
```

Disable street view.

```
streetViewControl: false
```

Answer (score 21):

**mapTypeControl and streetViewControl option to false**

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeFirst, longitudeFirst),
             zoom: 12,
             streetViewControl: false,
             mapTypeControl: false
        });
```

Answer (score 20):

You can hide them via css

```
.gm-style-mtc {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is not future proof. Better to use `mapTypeControlOptions`

Comment: that is not a solution

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Setting `mapTypeControl: false` and passing with other options worked for me. You may check spec [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in two ways:

1. JS

   ```
   streetViewControl: false,
   ```
2. CSS

   ```
   .gm-style-mtc {
     display: none;
   }
   ```